# Comparing set of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am interested in comparing two sets of dictionaries.I know that for doing this the dictionary has to be made hashable probably using a frozenset, but then what' an elegant way of doing comparisons of hashable dictionary keys ?

```
actual_set = [{
    'Cgroups': 'rwm',
    'PathInContainer': '/dev/xnull',
    'PathOnHost': '/dev/null'
}]

d = {
    'Cgroups': 'rwm',
    'PathInContainer': '/dev/xnull',
    'PathOnHost': '/dev/null'
}
hashed_devices = frozenset(expected_devices.items())

for key in hashed_devices:
    # assert actual_Set == set(hashed_Devices)
```

Here how can I compare the actual set with the hashed devices ?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing? Do you want to match all the keys or all the values or all the keys and values? Normally, `dict1 == dict2` should be enough.

Comment: What you're calling `actual_set` is not a `set` but actually a `list`...

Comment: I want to match the values of d with the values of actual set since the keys are static for me. Sorry i missed that information.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find if two dictionaries are same or not, the four they gave you the best answer: `dict1 == dict2`.

If you want to find what's the difference between two dictionaries, you can try the operation symmetric_difference() of set. For example,

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}

set1 = set(dict1.items())
set2 = set(dict2.items())
```

`set1.symmetric_difference(set2)` will show you a new set with (key, value) pairs which are either in dict1 or dict2 but not both, here is `set([('a', 1), ('d', 4)])`.

By the way, you can easily use dict() to convert it to a dictionary including the difference of dict1 and dict2.